# How to separate values in a variable in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

This may sound like a stupid question, but I am trying to separate the values in a variable so that I can cross compare them with another variable to decide what to do within an if statement.

Basically, I want to take the beginning letter of a users username, whatever letter that is, will then be compared to both variable to decide what action to take. So for example if the username is "Josh" the message "Home2" should appear. I'm not sure whether what I'm trying to achieve is possible but any help is appreciated.

```
$UserName = $env:username
$HomeDriveLetterAK = "\\charlie\home_A-K\$Username" 
$HomeDriveLetterAK = "\\charlie\home_L-Z\$Username"
$Home1 = "A, B, C, D, E, F"
$Home2 = "H, I, J, K, L, M"

If ($username.StartsWith($Home1, 1)) 
{
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home1" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error')
}
ElseIf ($username.StartsWith($Home2, 1))
{
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home2" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a Switch:

```
$username = "John"

Switch -Wildcard ( $username[0] )
{
 '[A-F]' { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home1" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error') }
 '[G-M]' { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home2" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error') }
 '[N-S]' { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home3" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error') }
 '[T-Z]' { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home4" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error') }
 Default { Write-Output 'Unable to determine "Home" for this user.'}
}
```

Comment: I think I like this better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, make `$Home1` & `$Home2` arrays, not CSV strings. I'll make parsing everything a lot easier. Then use the `ToCharArray()` method on the `String` object that is `$username` to get the first character, and the `-contains` operator to compare.

```sh
$Home1 = ("A","B","C","D","E","F")
$Home2 = ("H","I","J","K","L","M")
$FirstLetter = $username.ToCharArray()[0];
if ($Home1 -contains $FirstLetter) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home1" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error');
} elseif ($Home2 -contains $FirstLetter) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Home2" , "Status" , 'OK', 'error');
}
```

BTW, you probably want to fix the variable name in this line too:

```sh
$HomeDriveLetterAK = "\\charlie\home_L-Z\$Username"
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much, you have no idea how much this is going to help me!